# Mid-1960s Science Fiction Young Adult - Rocket to the moon

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the title of a young adult novel from 1964-1966. It has a group of high school geniuses who build a rocket ship and travel to the moon. A few boys and one girl. It is NOT Heinlein's Rocket Ship Galileo, nor any book by Heinlein. It included a teleporter, masers, lasers and travel to the star Alpha Centauri in a teleporter mishap. The boy and girl transported to Alpha Centauri make it back to Earth 9 years later, time lagged because of the teleporter speed of light transmission time and meet up with another of the original crew, now 9 years older. The book ends with the survivors destroying their landing module on the moon using a laser from earth. I forget the reason why. I recall a title like Foxfire, or Firefox, but that doesn't turn up anything on Google.

Comment: You got some good details going on there, but can I suggest you take a quick look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if it'll jog your memory so you can [edit] in any more details.

Comment: Has many elements of Harry Harrison's 1972 parody "Star Smashers of the Galaxy Rangers".

Comment: Nope, the book I'm thinking of it is definitely from the middle 1960's. Harry Harrison is great though.

Comment: Have Spacesuit Will Travel?

Comment: Not  Have Spacesuit Will Travel, nor any book by Heinlein.

Comment: *Star Smashers* had the unforgettable spacegoing 747 (using oxygen snow from Pluto to run the main engines, and an improvised RCS for maneuvering).  Not to mention the Cheddite projector that teleported the whole 747 (instantaneously, not at lightspeed).